# pppd issue: Hangup (SIGHUP) Modem hangup

Tags: networking, network-interface, modem, ppp, pppd

I am trying to connect a Telit moudle via USB interface on an embedded board. PPP connection is broken. From log, it shows “modem hangup” at the end.

I did some research on internet and found some people's log file is similar to mine. in their successful connection log message, modem will send a valid ip address to ISP. but in my case, it keeps repeating and finally gives up and showed `Hangup (SIGHUP) Modem hangup`

```
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1d <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1e <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
```

I was told by the person who sent me the SIM card the IP address is '166.155.125.033'.

Did I miss anything in my configuration file? I put full log and configurations below.

Thanks a lot for your inputs.

```
Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/ppp/net-chat-cellVerizon finished (pid 2286), status = 0x0
Serial connection established.
using channel 1
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB2
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xfdb2415d> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x0 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xff252d71> <pcomp> <accomp>]
No auth is possible
sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x0 <auth chap MD5>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xfdb2415d> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xff252d71> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xff252d71> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <deflate 15> <deflate(old#) 15> <bsd v1 15>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x2 magic=0xff252d71]
rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x3 80 fd 01 01 00 0f 1a 04 78 00 18 04 78 00 15 03 2f]
Protocol-Reject for 'Compression Control Protocol' (0x80fd) received
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x2 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x3 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x4 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x4 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x5 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x5 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x6 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x6 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x7 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x7 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x8 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x8 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x9 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x9 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xa <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0xa <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xb <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0xb <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xc <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0xc <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.1[  238.655851] random: crng init done
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xd <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0xd <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xe <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0xe <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0xf <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0xf <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x10 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x10 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x11 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x11 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x12 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x12 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x13 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x13 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x14 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
Hangup (SIGHUP)
Modem hangup
Connection terminated.
```

---

In the option file

```
debug
ttyUSB2
115200
crtscts
connect '/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/ppp/net-chat-cellVerizon'
noauth
defaultroute
mru 1500
logfile /etc/ppp/log
```

/etc/ppp/net-connect-cellVerizon file

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/chat -v -t 60 -f /etc/ppp/net-chat-cellVerizon
```

/etc/ppp/net-chat-cellVerizon file

```
TIMEOUT 5
ABORT   'ERROR'
''
'AT'
OK
'AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","so01.vzwstatic"'
OK
'ATD*99***1#'
CONNECT ''
```